# Adding two buttons to a form asp.net mvc5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to add two buttons to my page, an "Accept" button and a "Reject" button. I have done like so

```
 <button type="submit" name="SubmitButton" value="Accept" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Accept</button>
    <button type="submit" name="SubmitButton" value="Reject" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Reject</button>
```

Then in my controller I have the following

```
public ActionResult ViewRequest(string SubmitButton, int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            RequestLift requestLifts = db.requestLifts.Find(id);

            if (requestLifts == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            Lift lifts = db.Lifts.Find(id);

            if (SubmitButton == "Accept")
            {
                requestLifts.bookingStatus = "Accepted";
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else if (SubmitButton == "Reject")
            {
                requestLifts.bookingStatus = "Rejected";
                db.SaveChanges();t request has been rejected";
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            return View(requestLifts);
        }
```

However nothing happens on the button click?

```
    @Html.BeginForm("ViewRequest", "SubmitButton")
    {
    <button type="submit" name="SubmitButton" value="Accept" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Accept</button>
    <button type="submit" name="SubmitButton" value="Reject" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Reject</button>
}
```

Comment: `"nothing happens on the button click"` - If the form isn't being posted at all when you click the button then there's something wrong with your form, which has nothing to do with your controller action.

Comment: Please add your form code (either `<form>` tags or `Html.BeginForm()`)

Comment: I have never really used "Html.BeginFor()" Am I using it in the correct context?

Comment: `Html.BeginForm()` is like using `<form></form>` tags, so if take that into account if you want to submit something to processed. At the moment you're submitting nothing or probably only the `value` of the button clicked

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to wrap `Html.BeginForm` with `using`. This determines how the opening and closing form tags get added, i.e. *around the buttons within the form*. Your problem with submitting is that these buttons are not currently actually within your form tag.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ViewRequest", "SubmitButton"))
{
    <button type="submit" name="SubmitButton" value="Accept" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Accept</button>
    <button type="submit" name="SubmitButton" value="Reject" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Reject</button>
}
```

Comment: That works @Chris Pratt thanks. However s there a way to navigate to a different page then on button click? When I click either of the buttons it brings me  to /SubmitButton/ViewRequest?